# My local server is getting close to maximum resources, I want to add another server.

Tags: web-development, server, scalability

So, first let me explain my current setup. I have an unmanaged ethernet switch which is connected to my intel nuc (server A) and an external had drive.

Server A is running:

- Ubuntu
- Docker
- Gitlab container (I push my code to this, it builds an image adds it to docker and then replaces the old version)

My website is getting more traffic and the cpu and ram resources are starting to be the bottleneck, so I want to alleviate the resources by adding another intel nuc to my main one.

I have been looking at ways to do this, including multiple operating systems that apparently are built for things like this:

- CoreOS
- Centos

So my question is, how would I go about expanding my web server to allow more traffic, would I have to create 2 images of my website and upload it to both intel nucs, and then somehow load balance it so when Server A is at max cpu/ram capacity the traffic goes to Server 2? What software/operating systems would help with this situation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question isn’t about software, but the deployed environment supporting it. It would be better on one of our peer sites.

Comment: @Telastyn Hi, what website would you recommend me asking this on?

Comment: I don’t offhand since I don’t frequent those sites, but at first glance ServerFault or Webmasters might be a better fit. Double check their posting guidelines though. And hopefully someone else can comment on the best place for this.

Comment: its badly phrased, but we have a tonne of questions about scalable systems and deployments. I say its on topic, code has to run somewhere and that where often has implications for the design of the code

Comment: Quick note: a different OS is not going to help. Centos is just a variant of RHEL and is positioned similarly to Ubuntu for server deployments. CoreOS is not a normal Linux distribution but just a minimal platform for running containers, which is useful for running Kubernetes clusters. Neither of these OSes will save you noticeable CPU or RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Its not an operating system problem but a networking one.

Buy a new box and install your website on it.

Buy another box and install a load balancer such as HAProxy on it.

Point your domain name at the HAProxy box

Configure your HAProxy to route website traffic to the two web boxes.